# Ionic/Leaflet.js : How can I call a function from the L.Draw.Event.CREATED event?

Tags: ionic2, leaflet.draw

I am using Leaftlet Draw to draw simple shapes on a map. When the shape is created, I would like to call another method.

I am listening to the `CREATE` event like this:

```
drawMap() {
    this.myMap = L.map('map', {
        crs: L.CRS.Simple
    });

    ...

    this.myMap.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
      let type = e.layerType;
      let layer = e.layer;

      this.myOtherMethod();  // this.myOtherMethod is not a function

      drawLayer.addLayer(layer);
    });
}

myOtherMethod() {
    console.log('hello world!');
}
```

If I take `this.myOtherMethod();` out of the event listener, it will call it fine, so I know it is a scope problem. I am not sure how to call the parent scope.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using an anonymous function as a callback create a separate named function which can then call `myOtherMethod`

```
drawMap() {
    this.myMap = L.map('map', {
        crs: L.CRS.Simple
    });

    ...

    this.myMap.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED,this.onCreate.bind(this) );
}

onCreate (e) {
      let type = e.layerType;
      let layer = e.layer;

      this.myOtherMethod();  // this.myOtherMethod is not a function

      drawLayer.addLayer(layer);
}


myOtherMethod() {
    console.log('hello world!');
}
```

Comment: You sir - are AWESOME. Thank you so much!